If there are two overriden functions which one is called
The implmentation of the project is like this there is a function called foo wich is virtual, and there are two different and seperate contracts that override it. The contract wich has the virtual function calls foo. Wich one will it call?

please share code example for better response.

Hello, thank you for your awnser. There are two functions being overriden here https://etherscan.io/address/0x463F9ED5e11764Eb9029762011a03643603aD879?utm_source=immunefi#code#F1#L180
https://etherscan.io/address/0x463F9ED5e11764Eb9029762011a03643603aD879?utm_source=immunefi#code#F2#L468
And the function that calls this is here

Solidity doesn't use function names for executing in the EVM, it uses function signatures (which is a keccak function on the declaration, also called function selector). For this reason there can't be duplicated functions.because selector is unique. You can only have selector collision in delegate call, but I am pretty sure this is not your case. During compilation all conflicts in overriden funcitons is resolved so you can't have two functions with the same name converted to bytecode.
